# Reference member initialized from a by-value constructor parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, initialization, c++14

Under what conditions is this code correct:

```
struct A {
  A(B b) : b_(b) {}
 private:
  const B& b_;
}
B b_permanent;
A a(b_permanent);
```

IIUC, `b` will be a copy of `b_permanent`, and `b_` will be bound to that copy. But what is the lifetime of `b`? If it is only for the duration of the ctor, then this is wrong because `b_` will be bound to an out-of-scope object by the time ctor finishes. And if that's the case, why is it even legal in C++, and doesn't even cause lint warnings?

OTOH, if `b` lifetime is extended to equal the lifetime of `a`, then can you link me to a rule that states that?

Does the answer depend on whether `B` is a fundamental or compound type?

Does the answer depend on C++ 11 vs 14 vs 17? (I'm not interested in anything before 11.)

Comment: The lifetime of any *member* variable is the same as the object it resides int. For `a.b_` it has the same lifetime as `a`. Once `a` is destructed so are all its member variables. I think the question you want to really ask is about the lifetime of `b_permanent` instead?

Comment: To avoid this error, be on high alert when using a class with a reference member. It's rarely a good idea to have such members, outside of singleton objects

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I meant lifetime of `b`, not `b_`. Fixed typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-static member `b_` has the lifetime of the enclosing object. The object `b` has automatic storage duration since it's a function parameter, and it is destroyed when the constructor returns. So indeed `b_` becomes a dangling reference at that point.

It is *legal* to write code like this because detecting such code is a quality-of-implementation issue. Although in this case it's obvious that the code is wrong, reference-binding can involve more complicated logic to determine which object the reference is being bound to. It's impossible for the compiler to detect *in all cases* that this is occurring. If you want your toolchain to be able to catch *easy* cases like this one, file a feature request.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions about how to avoid this type of mistake in the less obvious cases (e.g., anti-patterns to watch out for, style to follow, etc)?

Comment: In general, you just have to be careful when storing references, because you have to have a guarantee that the object being referenced has a longer lifetime than your object.  Storing references also disables the automatic generation of assignment operators as you cannot reseat references.